# angular.equals() takes up 50% of execution time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, optimization, google-chrome-devtools

As most people do in their AngularJS career, I've hit a performance bottle neck in my app and I've been using the profiler in Chrome to try and find out why.

Just as an aside; I've done what I would consider normal optimisations for AngularJS apps and I do not have excessive watchers [~300].  I do however use Angular Google Maps and Angular Material.

The main thing that comes up in the profiler is a function called `equals` within AngularJS that takes up 50% of the time.  Interestingly though I don't use `angular.equals` in my code so I expect its some internal Angular process (digest cycle?) or external library - although I've checked the source code in most of the big libraries I use and they use `.equals()` sparingly.

Can anyone give me some hints as to where to look or what type of code to look at to find out what is causing these excessive equality checks?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the stack trace shows, `equals()` is being recursively called from `$digest`, when it evaluates all your watchers.

Watchers will use `angular.equals()` when you have used the `objectEquality` option, as indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

> When `objectEquality == true`, inequality of the `watchExpression` is determined according to the `angular.equals` function. To save the value of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used. **This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse memory and performance implications.**

So I would say the simplest answer is to either use fewer watchers or to use the `objectEquality` option more sparingly.

Comment: I guess it's about the dirty-checking system on the mechanism to detect changes, isn't it?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro That might also be a factor. I'm not that well versed in Angular's internals, but you can see how `$digest` is implemented [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/03043839d5a540b02208001fe12e812dfde00a8e/src/ng/rootScope.js).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did not know how the `objectEquality` option affected performance.  Having said that I use very few actual `$scope.$watch` and when I do I don't use `objectEquality`.  Is it better to do `$scope.$watch("expression", ...)` or `$scope.$watch(()=>{ return $scope.value; }, ...)`

Comment: Thinking about this a little more... If I have an AngularJS binding that is `ng-if="vehicle == $ctrl.selectedVehicle"` will it use `angular.equals` under the hood or will it just compare references?

Comment: @Chris AFAIK that should use the actual `==` operator and not `angular.equals`. And I don't think that there should be much of a difference in performance between `expression` and `() => { return $scope.value; }`. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Angular's inner workings to think of other things that might cause it to use `.equals()` behind the scenes.